# Gradle separated into script plugins with plugin repositories fails to find plugins

Tags: gradle, build, artifactory, gradle-plugin

When working in a team in a company setting with heavy regulations, with a local access-controlled artifactory (mirror and for publishing) and the official mirrors blocked in the firewall we need a common init.gradle. I have a real problem with hardcoding URLs (which should be part of the environment and not the project) into buildscripts and then repeating the same URLs across 100s of different projects. I see this more and more and it seems to particularly prevalent in gradle/android app and nodejs development circles.

This init.gradle works just fine - for application dependencies - not so much for plugins (the included version is being kept simple for demonstrations purposes). In particular, splitting the build into separate script plugins (not buildSrc or modular build) we can't use the plugins{} section; we have to use "apply plugin" in each script and thus we also need to add the plugin to the classpath in a buildscript section for each script.

**Well it still won't work. It does work if I put everything in a single root build.gradle file using a plugins section with versions and skip the classpath. So what am I doing wrong?**

See https://github.com/devminded/gradlebuild for full example.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'nebula.info' version '8.3.1'
    id 'nebula.lint' version '16.9.0'
}

apply from: 'gradle/build-package.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/build-docker.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/publish.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/release.gradle'
```

**gradle/build-docker.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:6.4.0'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'
// ...
```

**gradle/release.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.8.1'
   }
}
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'

release {
    // ...
}
afterReleaseBuild.dependsOn publish
```

**Result**

```
$> ./gradlew

Build file '.....\gradlebuild\build.gradle' line: 7

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myapp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:6.4.0 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```java
apply plugin: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.DockerRemoteApiPlugin
```

instead of

```java
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'
```

you can find the plugin's class path on its repository [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/blob/4e6332c38c1ba3e3c3721fef9f0e8798dc7839d7/src/main/groovy/com/bmuschko/gradle/docker/DockerRemoteApiPlugin.groovy#L30)